# Argument ‘#1’ cannot convert ‘string[][]’ expression to type ‘string’ - MonoTouch

Tags: arrays, xamarin.ios, jagged-arrays

I am trying to submit an array in MonoTouch to a vb.net web service.  Here is the web service:

```
Public Function Add_Array(ByVal arr()() As String, ByRef sMessage As String) As Boolean 
Dim a, b, c As String a = arr(1)(0) b = arr(1)(1) c = arr(1)(2) sMessage = a + ", " + b + ", " + c + ". Submittion was recieved, and Second items are showen." 
Return True 
End Function
```

I added the web service by going to Add Web Reference, adding in the Web Service URL, and selecting .NET 2.0 Web Services as the Framework and then wsFish as the reference.

Here is my MonoTouch code:

```
wsFISH.Service1 wsArray;
string[][] abc = new string[6][];
string[] xyz = new string[3];
string t="";

xyz[0] = “a”;
xyz[1] = “b”;
xyz[2] = “c”;
abc[0] = xyz;  ...

wsArray.Add_Array(abc, ref t);
```

This is the error I am getting: “The best overloaded method match for ‘Add_Array(string, ref string)’ has some invalid arguments Argument ‘#1’ cannot convert ‘string[][]’ expression to type ‘string’”

I have written C# code outside of monotouch that will access the web service using the exact code I have in monotouch.  Any ideas?

Comment: It does not seem the `Add_Array(string[][] arr, ref string sError)` is part of the web service (generated code) you're referencing. Can you edit your question to add (part of) the generated code (e.g. all Add_Array overloads) ?

Comment: @poupou I am new to this so I don't know if I totally understand what you mean by overloads.  I am assuming you mean the different variables in the Add_Arry.  I have added the web service in full and described how I have added the web service to monotouch.  Let me know if you need more information.  THANKS!

Comment: This could be an issue with the generated code.  It may have been generating code for Add_Array with a string as the first param, not a multidimensional array of strings.  I would check to see if that's the case.  You can probably fix that by hand.

Comment: @DaveFerguson I created a C# web application in Visual Studio and ran this code, referenced the same web service that I am trying to reference in MonoTouch, and the code worked.  So I must be missing what I need to do different in MonoTouch.  This is what I think you are saying, that the web service that MonoTouch is seeing is only a string.  I know that is true.  But I also know that the web service is correct as I can access it both with VB, and C# (built in Visual Studio).  So how do I "fix it by hand" in MonoTouch?  I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: @jcameron13 The web service is running separately from MT.  What is happening is that a set of proxy classes are being generated for you when you add the web service reference.  You can always update these generated files by hand.  You could also copy the generated classes from a VS.NET web service reference (theoretically, unless the generated code uses an api that mono hasn't implemented yet).  It's likely a bug in the web service proxy code generation of MD.  Last time I was using MD for web services, that wasn't implemented yet, so I'm guessing it is fairly new.

Comment: @DaveFerguson I was able to update the code, but I keep getting an error, so I changed the web service to just a Hello World.  It won't even connect to that.  I keep getting: "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I found.  There are two parts to it.
First, I needed to add the correct references:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Web.Services;
```

Second, I was using a Jagged array which did add some issues.  Doing what @DaveFerguson suggested (changing the generated code) was the solution to this.